# XML сериализация сложного класса

Tags: c#, xml, сериализация

Имеется довольно сложная структура следующего вида:

```
[Serializable]
public class A
{
    public int a1 {get;set;}
    public bool a2 { get; set; }
    public string a3 { get; set; }
    .......
}

[Serializable]
public class B
{
    public int b1 { get; set; }
    public bool b2 { get; set; }
    public string b3 { get; set; }

    public List<A> ba1 { get; set; }

    public List<string> ba2 { get; set; }
    ......
}
```

Третий день бьюсь над XML сериализацией класса B.

Выдает ошибку

> 'Тип "SLib.AccountCfg" с именем контракта данных
>   "AccountCfg:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/SLib" не
>   ожидается. Попробуйте использовать DataContractResolver, если вы
>   используете DataContractSerializer, или добавьте любые статически
>   неизвестные типы в список известных типов - например, используя
>   атрибут KnownTypeAttribute или путем их добавления в список известных
>   типов, передаваемый в сериализатор.'

Сама процедура сериализации

```
    public void Save(PhoneCfg inConfig)
    {
        XmlTextWriter xw = new XmlTextWriter("Sets.xml", Encoding.UTF8);
        xw.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
        XmlDictionaryWriter writer = 
        XmlDictionaryWriter.CreateDictionaryWriter(xw);
        DataContractSerializer ser = new 
        DataContractSerializer(typeof(PhoneCfg));
        ser.WriteObject(writer, inConfig);
        writer.Close();
        xw.Close();
    }
```

Что я делаю не так?

---

Реально это файлы настройки SIP-телефонии

```
[Serializable]
public class AccountCfg : IAccount
{
    public AccountCfg() { }

    public int Index { get; set; }
    public string AccountName { get; set; }
    public string HostName { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public string DomainName { get; set; }
    public int RegState { get; set; }
    public string ProxyAddress { get; set; }
    public ETransportMode TransportMode { get; set; }

    public bool Enabled { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Id;
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class PhoneCfg : IConfiguratorInterface
{
    private List<IAccount> m_Accounts;
    private int m_DefaultAccountIndex=0;
    private bool m_IsNull;

    public PhoneCfg()
    {
    }

    public bool DNDFlag { get; set; }
    public bool AAFlag { get; set; }
    public bool CFUFlag { get; set; }
    public string CFUNumber { get; set; }
    public bool CFNRFlag { get; set; }
    public string CFNRNumber { get; set; }
    public bool CFBFlag { get; set; }
    public string CFBNumber { get; set; }
    public int SIPPort { get; set; }
    public int DefaultAccountIndex { get => m_DefaultAccountIndex; set => m_DefaultAccountIndex = value; }
    public List<string> CodecList { get; set; }
    public bool PublishEnabled { get; set; }
    public List<IAccount> Accounts { get => m_Accounts; set => m_Accounts = value; }
    public bool IsNull { get => m_IsNull; set => m_IsNull = value; }

    public string StunServerAddress { get; set; }
    public EDtmfMode DtmfMode { get; set; }
    public int iDtmfMode { get; set; }
    public int Expires { get; set; }
    public int ECTail { get; set; }
    public bool VADEnabled { get; set; }
    public string NameServer { get; set; }
    public int defaultATime { get; set; }

    public void Save()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Сама процедура сериализации public void Save(PhoneCfg inConfig)
        {
            XmlTextWriter xw = new XmlTextWriter("Sets.xml", Encoding.UTF8);
            xw.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
            XmlDictionaryWriter writer = XmlDictionaryWriter.CreateDictionaryWriter(xw);
            DataContractSerializer ser = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(PhoneCfg));
            ser.WriteObject(writer, inConfig);
            writer.Close();
            xw.Close();
        }

Comment: А почему так сложно? Почему просто не использовать `XmlSerializer`? Ну а вообще, у меня лично не удалось воспроизвести вашу проблему, вроде и классы прям скопировал и сериализацию вашу - результат - файл на месте (правда вида ужасного, но это другой вопрос как по мне..)

Comment: Вы показали классы `A` и `B`, а сериализуете `PhoneCfg`. Покажите класс `PhoneCfg`.

Comment: Почитайте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/823923/%D0%92-%D0%A7%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-xml-serializer-%D0%B8-xml-writer-%D0%B2-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0/823962#823962

Answer (score 1):

Пометьте свой класс атрибутом:

```
[KnownType(typeof(AccountCfg))]
public class AccountCfg : IAccount
```

Тогда сериализатор будет знать, какие возможны реальные типы вместо интерфейса в этом свойстве:

```
public List<IAccount> Accounts
```

Другой возможный вариант - добавить определения известных типов при создании сериализатора:

```
var knownTypes = new List<Type> { typeof(AccountCfg) };

var ser = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(PhoneCfg),
    new DataContractSerializerSettings { KnownTypes = knownTypes });
```