# В Чем различие между XML Serializer и XML Writer в форматировании документа?

Tags: c#

Есть класс, который реализует `ISerializable`. 
В нем есть метод

```
    public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
    {
        writer.WriteStartElement(nameof(MyClass));
        writer.WriteAttributeString("IntAttribute", Int.ToString());
        writer.WriteEndElement();
    }
```

Если его вызвать напрямую, т.е. `myObj.WriteXml`, то выходной файл получается таким: 
 `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><MyClass IntAttribute="5" />`

Но если его вызывает `XmlSerializer`, то выходной файл уже немного другой (появилось форматирование):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MyClass>
  <MyClass IntAttribute="5" />
</MyClass>
```

Как сделать так, чтобы и при ручном вызове было нормальное форматирование?

Вызов этого метода:

```
        var myObj = new MyClass();
        var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyClass));
        using (var stream = new StreamWriter("file2.xml"))
        {
            ser.Serialize(stream, myObj);
        }

        var settings = new XmlWriterSettings
        {
            NewLineOnAttributes = true,
            NewLineChars        = Environment.NewLine
        };
        using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create("file1.xml", settings))
        {
            myObj.WriteXml(writer);
        }
```

Определение класса:

```
public class MyClass:IXmlSerializable
{
    public int Int = 5;

    public MyClass() {}

    #region Implementation of IXmlSerializable

    public XmlSchema GetSchema() => null;

    public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
        return;
    }

    public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
    {
        writer.WriteStartElement(nameof(MyClass));
        writer.WriteAttributeString("IntAttribute", Int.ToString());
        writer.WriteEndElement();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Как мне добиться хоть какого-то форматирования при использовании `myObj.WriteXml`? 
Сейчас мой код вызова этого метода выглядит как

```
        var myObj = new MyClass();
        var settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
        settings.Indent = true;
        using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create("file1.xml", settings))
        {
            myObj.WriteXml(writer);
        }
```

Форматирование появилось.

Comment: У `XmlWriterSettings` есть свойство `Indent`, похоже это вас должно заинтересовать.

Comment: @Bulson, ничего не меняется. Indent - это же отступы, нет? В любом случае, с вашим вариантом XmlWriter все равно пишет все в одну строку. Несмотря на то, что я в ' IndentChars ' поставил 
    'Environment.NewLine'

Comment: Попробуйте `writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented`

Comment: Ваши xml различаются не только форматированием, но и структурой. В одном случае у вас только _атрибут_, в другом - вложенный _элемент_ с атрибутом. И покажите определение `MyClass`.

Comment: @АндрейNOP, у writer нет такого свойства.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, добавил описание класса. Он почти пустой, кода нет.

Comment: В `XmlWriterSettings` свойство `Indent`, про которое в первом же комментарии написали, установили в `true`? Не `IndentChars` (это другое свойство). Если да, то форматирование появится. Но, укажу ещё раз, структура xml в обоих случаях различается.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, да, я поставил Indent еще после первого комментария.

Comment: **Невозможно** отформатировать то, чего нет. В одном случае выводится обрамляющий элемент, в другом нет. Dixi.

Comment: Теперь вы забыли передать `settings` в метод `Create`.

Comment: @VictorGorban, да, действительно, это свойство XmlTextWriter (это наследник XmlWriter), используйте его: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.xml.xmltextwriter(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При использовании XmlWriter вы берете на себя ответственность за выяснение связей между подузлами, корректную расстановку начальных и конечных тестов, а также постановку атрибутов.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb))
using (XmlTextWriter xtw = new XmlTextWriter(sw))
{
     xtw.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
     xtw.WriteStartElement("Book");
     xtw.WriteAttributeString("PublishYear", "2009");
     xtw.WriteStartElement("Title");
     xtw.WriteString("Programming, art or engineering?");
     xtw.WriteEndElement();
     xtw.WriteStartElement("Author");
     xtw.WriteString("Billy Bob");
     xtw.WriteEndElement();
     xtw.WriteEndElement();
}

Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());

Console.ReadKey();
```

При использовании Serializer все выполняется автоматически, но необходимо учитывать, сериализуются только открытые типы и открытые члены этих типов.

Comment: Отлично, как мне устроить это форматирование?

Comment: я в ответ добавил пример